# How to detect deprecated direct dependencies in a pipeline for a go project

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying to detect direct deprecated dependencies in a go project. For that I created the a dummy project [deptest](https://github.com/zbindenren/deptest) which has [depricon](https://github.com/zbindenren/depricon) direct dependency. As stated in [go1.17 release notes](https://go.dev/doc/go1.17) under the **Module deprecation comments** section it should be possible to get the deprecated dependencies with `go list -m -u` . But when I run the command in my project I get:

```
$ go list -m -u 
github.com/zbindenren/deptest
```

I see the deprecation warning only with the following commands:

```
$ go get ./...
go: module github.com/zbindenren/depricon is deprecated: This module is not maintained anymore.
```

Or with:

```
$ go list -m -u all
github.com/zbindenren/deptest
github.com/zbindenren/depricon v0.0.1 (deprecated)
```

But with the second command I also get all indirect deprecateded dependencies.

My question is: is this a bug that `go list -m -u` doesn't show the deprecated modules? And is there maybe a better way to check for deprecated modules than running `go get ./...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when you run `go list -m -u` without a module argument, it lists only the main module ([source](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-list-m)):

> The -m flag causes go list to list modules instead of packages. [...] If no arguments are specified, the main module is listed.

Then, the release notes of Go 1.17 actually state that:

> `go list -m -u` prints deprecations for all dependencies **(use -f or -json to show the full message)**

So run with a module argument that includes your deprecated dependency, and specify the format:

```
$ go list -m -u -f '{{.Path}} {{.Deprecated}}' all
github.com/zbindenren/deptest 
github.com/zbindenren/depricon This module is not maintained anymore.
```

If you want to limit output to only *direct* dependencies, use a template trick:

```
$ go list -m -u -f '{{if not .Indirect}}{{.Path}} {{.Deprecated}}{{end}}' all
```

Or wait for [this proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40364) to come through.

Comment: Using templates did the trick. I updated your command to only print deprecated modules:  `go list -m -u -f '{{if and (not .Indirect) .Deprecated }}{{.Path}} {{.Version}} (deprecated: {{.Deprecated}}){{end}}' all` gives `github.com/zbindenren/depricon v0.0.1 (deprecated: This module is not maintained anymore.)` as result.

Comment: Hopefully they'll introduce `direct` in 1.19 and this template magic will (in part) go away. Though even then you still have to use the template to print *only* the deprecated deps